# Implement autoplay, pause on hover, keyboard control on slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, autoplay

I am trying to implement [this sideshow](http://tympanus.net/Development/ItemTransitions/) on a project, and I want to add some features :

- Auto-play
- Pause on hover
- Multiple instance of the slider
- Go to next slide with keyboard arrow keys

**What I have tried ?**

I have added this code

```
        var autoscroll = window.setInterval(function(){ navigate( 'next' )}, 5000);

    component.onmouseover = function(e){
        autoscroll = clearInterval(autoscroll);
        console.log('onmouseover');
    };
    component.onmouseout = function(e) {
            clearInterval(autoscroll);
            var autoscroll = setInterval(function() {navigate( 'next' )}, 5000);
            console.log('onmouseout');
    };
```

*Live Demo:* http://jsfiddle.net/M2CwF/1/

**What is the problem ?**

- The autoplay works fine until we manually use the control arrow, I see that the interval will change in this case, maybe I need to add a condition like `if( isAnimating ) return false;`
- The pause on hover does not seems to work, and from the console log I see that the event is fired several times in just one single hover !
- If I have multiple instance of the slider only the first one works
- The keyboard keys to pass to next slide

  Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with how you were handling the mouseover and mouseout was that you were redefining the global autoscroll variable instead of changing its value in the mouseout event.

Changing that and some relatively simple keydown event code fixed up the slideshow to do what you want (I think).

The changes I made to the mouseover/mouseout code:

```
var autoscroll = window.setInterval(function(){ navigate( 'next' )}, 5000);

        component.onmouseover = function(e){
            autoscroll = clearInterval(autoscroll);
            console.log('onmouseover');
        };
        component.onmouseout = function(e) {
                clearInterval(autoscroll);
                autoscroll = setInterval(function() {navigate( 'next' )}, 5000);
                console.log('onmouseout');
        };
```

And here's the code for the arrow key events:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    switch (event.keyCode || event.which) {
        case 37:
            clearInterval(autoscroll);
            navigate( 'prev' );
            autoscroll = setInterval(function() {navigate( 'next' )}, 5000);
            break;
        case 39:
            clearInterval(autoscroll);
            navigate( 'next' );
            autoscroll = setInterval(function() {navigate( 'next' )}, 5000);
            break;
    }
};
```

Here's what I came up with:
http://jsfiddle.net/M2CwF/2/

**Update**

Here's a version that supports multiple slideshows per page.  I eliminated the left and right arrow actions though because I'm not sure how you would want to handle navigating multiple slideshows on one page...

It shouldn't be hard to modify the code to make that happen though.

http://jsfiddle.net/M2CwF/5/

Comment: Excellent, Thank you for the effort, this is really what I need, just if you can add the solution to handle multiple instance in the same page and I will accept your answer

Comment: Ahh, I missed that bit.  That could prove to be a bit of a challenge but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I am trying as well to find a solution, I have converted the script to a php file generated dynamically and I pass the id of the module :

 `<script src="js/main.php?moduleid=107"></script>
  <script src="js/main.php?moduleid=108"></script>`

 and Inside the file I rename the component

`component = document.getElementById( 'component$moduleid' ),`

now only the last one with the id 108 works, do I need to change another think to make them independent. thank you

Comment: Ok, I modified the code.  Took a bit of time!  I would definitely recommend finding a new slider if you can help it though.  This one is a bit "hackish."

Comment: wow you really made my day, thank you from the bottom of my heart. just about the hakish stuff, I really like the animation of the slider and it was published a a proof of concept and unfortunately I am a back-end developer and have no deep knowledge of JS so I couldn't make something clean using the animations of that slider ... thank you one more time